# Add extra data as part of url and not as parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

So I've read about `routes` in `MVC` and configured according to what's mentioned in other posts.. So my intention is to generate url as below:

```
http://domain.com/controller/action/id
```

with this intention I've configured my `RoutesConfig.cs` as below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "AdminMessage",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Messages", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Below is what my Controller looks like

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Messages(string id)
{
    _model = new AdminViewModel();
    _userName = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    ViewBag.Page = "Messages";
    _model = PrepareLayoutModel(_userName, "Messages");
    return View(_model);
}
```

And I use `Url.Action` to generate `url` as below:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Messages", "Admin", new RouteValueDictionary(new {message.MessageID}))"></a>
```

But it always generates `Url` as `http://domainname/controller/action?messageID=SDc@#123#2@`, instead I want to generate it as `http://domainname/controller/action/SDc@#123#2@`. So what is the way I can get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be

```
@Url.Action("Messages", "Admin", new { ID = message.MessageID })
```

Which creates an object with a property named `ID` (which matches your route) as opposed to your current implemenatation which is using an object property named `MessageID` which does not match your route so its value is added as a query string value

Comment: Perfect.. Silly mistakes keep on happening.. :(

Comment: Can I ask one more doubt here? How can I get `id` parameter in `Razor view`? I tried with `Request.QueryString[0]` and `Request.QueryString["id"]` but both the times it returned `null`.. Will the last part now will be treated as `querystring`? How can I get this?

Comment: Because you have `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",` then the value is added a a route value, not a query string value. But because the parameter in the method is `string id`, then that parameter will be the value of `message.MessageID` (and you can also access route values using `HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];` but that is unnecessary)

Comment: Yea.. That's correct.. :) Thanks much for the info.. Have a pleasant time.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Messages", "Admin", new { id = message.MessageID })"></a>
```

or even better use the `Html.ActionLink` helper that will generate an anchor tag pointing to the desired controller action and passing the `id` route parameter value:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    linkText: "", 
    actionName: "Messages", 
    controllerName: "Admin", 
    routeValues: new { id = message.MessageID }, 
    htmlAttributes: null
)
```

This being said, if you intend to be passing special characters in the route portion of your urls you should [`be prepared to suffer`](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx). In this case I would simply recommend you using query string parameters which can be more than safely url encoded without you suffering. So basically if you do not control the format of this `MessageID` parameter and narrow it down to basic alphanumeric characters you more than totally don't want it as part of your route segments.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info @Darin.. I forgot to mention that I cannot use `@Html.ActionLink` because there are some other elements which comes inside the `a` tag... Thanks much for time and help.. :)

Comment: plus 20 in different ways.. ;)

Comment: I can't think of any viable reason against using standard HTML helpers such as `Html.ActionLink`. Even if you need to put some of your own crap inside the link text you could always have written a custom HTML helper instead of ending with such terrible spaghetti mixture between HTML DOM markup and server side helpers as attributes of thos DOM elements.

Comment: Well, then I have to look into creating a custom HTML helper as my knowledge on them is very limited.. Definitely I will look into it buddy.. :) Thank you.. :)

Comment: Oh you definitively should look into creating custom HTML helpers. I can hardly believe how people are even using Razor in real world applications without customizing it.

Comment: Yea Darin.. My ways of using it are worst even and I made this point after you have made your last statement.. Feeling sad but yea definitely I'll take a look of that.. :) You have written any blogs on this so that I can follow you.. :)